# ASP.NET Core and NextAuthJS

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, next-auth

I have 3 individual applications:

- IdentityServer4
- JS client using Next and NextAuth.js for authentication.
- ASP.NET Core Rest API

The identity server runs in a different domain than the others:

```
https://login.example.com
```

On the other hand the client and the API run in the same domain

- https://app.example.com => Next
- https://app.example.com/api-rest => ASP.NET Core

Since they share the same domain, I would like asp to directly use the cookie that NextAuth uses.

The Rest API is expecting the access token in the header (`Authorization: Bearer <token>`). To be able to add that ASP.NET Core reads apart from the authentication header (since it is used by other apps...) add that cookie authentication can also come.

Simply what I do is read the cookie with:

```
context.Request.Cookies["next-auth.session-token"]
```

and decrypt it.

But that's where I have a problem. The JWT that sends next is not the accessToken, it is a JSON that contains the Access token:

```
{
  "accessToken": "a.b.c",
  "refreshToken": "asasa",
  "user": {
    "id": "d3223",
    "name": "Test"
  },
  "iat": 1652801889,
  "exp": 1655393889,
  "jti": "27c172ff-f579-4271-a3ca-c77393630f1b"
}
```

But the questions arise:

- How do I make ASP.NET Core take the Access Token that is inside the JWT itself, that is, I would have to do something like double decoding?
- Is there another way to share the Access token more transparently while maintaining encryption?